# Django testing model manager

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I add task function in model manager ***create***

```
class _Manager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, **kwargs):
        obj = super(_Manager, self).create(**kwargs)
        task_1.after(15 * 60, obj.pk)
        return obj

class Note(models.Model):
    objects = _Manager()

    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

I use [django-ztask](https://github.com/dmgctrl/django-ztask) for tasks

I try test my manager

```
class ManagerTest(TestCase):
    def test_create(self):
        note = Note.objects.create(title='note 1')
        task = Task.objects.get(function_name='note.tasks.task_1')
        self.assertTrue(task)
```

Test failure, task is empty array

How I write a correct test for manager?

Comment: is the `Task` available when it is registered? or after the 15 * 60 time is up?